# Where can I ask about what to call a particular job role?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, meta

I *think* I'm asking if there's a Stack Overflow Jobs Meta... but I don't think there is.

I have a client who's looking to hire someone with a particular job description, and they've asked me what that person's title would be (it's someone to do rich web advertising and HTML email design, FWIW) ... I don't know what the established title is, and I'm a bit stuck as to where to ask...

Comment: Just list all expected skills and add "architest" at the end. It's how it's usually done I guess. If you want a real killer add "guru" as prefix.

Comment: I guess that would work for advertising, but it doesn't help for research in the market...

Comment: Note sure if this would be on topic on the workplace, could ask on their meta.

Comment: If your client were to post the listing on Stack Overflow Jobs, our sales reps would certainly help choosing the best title to attract relevant candidates :) I'm closing this as off-topic as it's not really a question about /jobs ;)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, this type of question would be off-topic for Stack Overflow, and no, there isn't a Meta site specifically for Stack Overflow Jobs. In fact, I don't know of any place on the Stack Exchange network where career-related questions would be accepted. (They are problematic for many reasons, including temporal and geographic sensitivity, not to mention the open-ended nature.)

Although I don't know for sure, I imagine that the sales people you deal with from Stack Overflow Jobs would be able to help you with this. I mean, they're not going to write your ad for you, but you *are* paying them for providing a service, and they've had experience with plenty of other clients, so it seems reasonable to ask for their input and benefit from their accumulated wisdom. That is the closest you'll get to a Meta site.

Otherwise, you will just need to do your own research—looking around at similar job postings, browsing developer blogs, etc. Keeping up-to-date on this type of information about the industry is presumably why your "client" came to you to help fill their job opening and/or provide advice.

I don't know much about this particular area, either, but it *sounds* like you want someone to do front-end web development. Or maybe just a graphical designer, specializing in online/electronic media (depending on if there is any actual programming required).